# Code for consecutive strings works but can't pass random tests

Tags: python, string, list

In this problem, I'm given an array(list) `strarr` of strings and an integer k. My task is to return the first longest string consisting of k consecutive strings taken in the array. My code passed all the sample tests from CodeWars but can't seem to pass the random tests.

[Here's the link to the problem.](https://www.codewars.com/kata/56a5d994ac971f1ac500003e)

I did it in two days. I found the max consecutively combined string first. Here's the code for that.

```
strarr = []

def longest_consec(strarr, k):
    strarr.append('')
    length = len(strarr)
    cons_list = []
    end = k
    start = 0
    freq = -length/2
    final_string = []
    largest = max(strarr, key=len, default='')
    if k == 1:
        return largest
    elif 1 < k < length:
        while(freq <= 1):
            cons_list.append(strarr[start:end])
            start += k-1
            end += k-1
            freq += 1
        for index in cons_list:
            final_string.append(''.join(index))
        return max(final_string, key=len, default='')  
    else:
        return ""
```

Since that didn't pass all the random tests, I compared the combined k strings on both sides of the single largest string. But, this way, the code doesn't account for the case when the single largest string is in the middle. Please help.

```
strarr = []

def longest_consec(strarr, k):
    strarr.append('')
    length = len(strarr)
    largest = max(strarr, key=len, default='')
    pos = int(strarr.index(largest))
    if k == 1:
        return largest
    elif 1 < k < length:
        prev_string = ''.join(strarr[pos+1-k:pos+1])
        next_string = ''.join(strarr[pos:pos+k])
        if len(prev_string) >= len(next_string):
            res = prev_string
        else: 
            res = next_string
        return res
    else:
        return ""

print(longest_consec(["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe"], 2))
```

Comment: I'd suggest to start by renaming all your variables. Never name your variables a,b,p, q... Put descriptive names so we can understand what each variable is supposed to do. Looking a your code I have to idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: "return the first longest string consisting of k consecutive strings in an array": I don't understand that. Could you give a pointer to the actual description of the problem; I assume it's a link to a Codewars webpage?

Comment: The actual problem description is also necessary to know what to do in case of awkward/bad inputs. A test would check that, and we don't know if your code does the right thing in that case.

Comment: Reflecting on Sembei's comment: your code is very C-style, not Python-style. I'm not sure what your programming background is, but this definitely isn't the way you should code in Python.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki - unless "p" and "q" are the natural names for your variables.  When I am writing RSA in python, pylint's objection to variables called p, q, n, and e is very annoying!

Comment: I don't see how p and q can be the natural names of the variables. q seems to be a list where the OP is appending things, and p... not sure, p = -a, and a seems to be a length of a string. Very confusing overall.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the first statement of your function:

```py
if k == 1:
    while(p <= 1):
        b.append(strarr[j:i])
        j += 1
        i += 1
        p += 1
    for w in b:
        q.append(''.join(w))
    return max(q, key=len)
```

Here *q* is finally equal *strarr* so you can shorten this code to:

```py
if k == 1:
    return max(strarr, key=len)
```

I see that second statement's condition checks if *k* value is between 1 and length of string array inclusive:

```py
elif k > 1 and k <= 2*a:
    ...
```

If you want no errors remove equality symbol, last element of every array has index lesser than its length (equal exactly length of it minus 1).
Ceiling and division is not necessary in *a* definition, so you can shorten this:

```py
a = ceil(len(strarr)/2)
```

into this:

```py
a = len(strarr)
```

then your *elif* statement may look like below:

```py
elif 1 < k < a:  # Same as (k > 1 and k < a)
    ...
```

again, I see you want to concatenate (add) the longest string to *k* next strings using this code:

```py
while(p <= 1):
    b.append(strarr[j:i])
    j += k-1
    i += k-1
    p += 1
for w in b:
    q.append(''.join(w))
return max(q, key=len)
```

the more clearer way of doing this:

```py
longest = max(strarr, key=len)  # Longest string in array.
index = 0  # Index of the current item.
for string in strarr:
    # If current string is equal the longest one ...
    if string == longest:
        # Join 'k' strings from current index (longest string index).
        return ''.join(strarr[index:index + k])
    index += 1  # Increase current index.
```

And the last statement which is:

```py
elif k > 2*a or k<1:
    return ""
```

if all previous statements failed then value is invalid so you can instead write:

```py
return ""  # Same as with else.
```

Now everything should work. I advice you learning the basics (especially lists, strings and slices), and please name your variables wisely so they are more readable.

Comment: I need the first largest concatenated string. When I change `zone` to `zones`, I still get `abigailtheta`.

Comment: So you want to join next *k* items after **the pair of items** which creates the largest string when concatenated?

Comment: [Here's the link to the problem](https://www.codewars.com/kata/56a5d994ac971f1ac500003e)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well

###### this has passed all the test cases on the platform you suggested.

```
def longest_consec(strarr, k):
  i = 0
  max_ = ""
  res = ""
  if (k<=0) or (k>len(strarr)):
        return ""
  while i<=(len(strarr)-k):
    start = "".join(strarr[i:i+k])
    max_ = max(max_, start, key=len)
    if max_==start:
      res=strarr[i:i+k]
    i+=1
  return max_

#output: ["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas", "theta", "abigail"], 2 -> abigailtheta
#output: ["zones", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas", "theta", "abigail"],2 -> zonesabigail
```

Comment: @PromelaTajrina I have tested this code on the link you have given and it has passed all the test cases.